# How to return object from Django Query?

Tags: django, object, return

I have one method:

```
@staticmethod
    def select_one(sql, params=None):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        return result
```

...but returning: `[{'object':'value'}, {'object2':'value'}]`.
I think bad user `return obj[0]` when I want to return only one object. Anyone know a way better or more correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of results.

```
if len(result) > 0:
    return result[0]
```

Comment: It's the only way? "...I think bad user return obj[0]..."